# How to execute a function when a tray icon menu action is pressed?

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu, qaction

```cpp
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication oApp( argc, argv );

    QAction *action1;
    QMenu menu;

    QSystemTrayIcon TrayIcon( QIcon("favicon.ico") );

    TrayIcon.show();

    action1= new QAction("action1", NULL);

    action1->setStatusTip("Create a new file");


    menu.addAction(action1);
    TrayIcon.setContextMenu(&menu);

    return oApp.exec();
}
```

How can I make it so that when I open the menu and press on `action1`,  a function is executed?

Answer (score 4):

Create new class (derived from QObject) with a slot called, e.g. myslot, then:

```
class MyClass : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
...
public slots:
    void mySlot();
};

myObject = new MyClass();
connect(action1, SIGNAL(triggered()), myObject, SLOT(mySlot()));
```